# A problem with getting different Modules based on the type of Module passed in

Tags: typescript

I want to pass in an array of different types so that I can get different combinations of submodules.

But I pass in a single type which is fine, and when I pass in multiple types, it compiles incorrectly.

How do I change this?

```
export enum Module {
  'Video' = 0,
  'Chat',
}

export interface ModulesMaps {
  [Module.Video]: VideoModule;
  [Module.Chat]: ChatModule;
}

export interface VideoModule {
  getVideoModule():  string;
}

export interface ChatModule {
  getChatModule():  string;
}

export interface CommonModule {
  init(): void;
}

export type Core<T extends Module> = CommonModule & ModulesMaps[T]

export function createClient<T extends Module>(modules: T[]): Core<T>{
  // fake code
  return undefined as unknown as Core<T>;
}

let client1 = createClient([Module.Video]);
client1.getVideoModule();
client1.init();

let client2 = createClient([Module.Chat]);
client2.getChatModule();
client2.init();

let client3 = createClient([ Module.Chat | Module.Video  ]);
client3.getVideoModule(); //compile error
client3.getChatModule(); //compile error
client3.init();
```

Playground : [typescriptlang.org playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEFkoBNUA2ICA3sAggOQBqAlriFJQgLwIAMANOVQMIAWAQziVuAX2ChIsRLWRwQMAGaCAxsRz4iAZyyCI20jwDamwiAB0dBlAC6ALgTXGZogG4TrywOEOEPuC8PCSloeAQ5BWU1YmcoLyMKAHMQODivAAoASkcEbTgYOSTgyXAw2XlFFXV-IUC8c0SEFLgAzJyKfMLkYuAQspkIyuia3ih0dChkBLIKOVo4bMcANyh6EtDBuABPCGIxmBAAHgAVJDAFZFxDLwA+Vn9xyemGogQAMmxXkF19bWMTrZStJwkpUMhVHBaFMEKpDsIQLwCLQUHBTudLtcvloQLcMpMcdpHCdjLYOgdjidbrMEAB6WkIFQAa2IqjwIB4hzgqBgyAQ4IYSjkIFwCEEhnBTOQUAA7nzxY9DqdbhsiIhVMjUQBGB5wkAIpEo+QZUzfKz0Rhkjwao1wLUWFrpb7Za2a+T2+aLLIeYBq2FuuAAJl18IUhtRJq8FgCVuANtRgYdqTazu9cYDic9Lskfvj8gAzCH9WGAybseZo3UEAAfctEc02CixvNwfNJtIW+Kp122tstFM47MtttZ71AA)

I want to pass in an array of different types so that I can get different combinations of submodules.

But I pass in a single type which is fine, and when I pass in multiple types, it compiles incorrectly.

How do I change this?

Comment: re:`[Module.Chat | Module.Video]` if you intend to use `|` in runtime your Module should be binary flags (1, 2, 4, 8, 16). You want `,` there I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rewriting as

```
export type Core<T extends Module> = CommonModule & { foo: ModulesMaps[T] }
export function createClient<T extends Module>(modules: T[]): Core<T> & unknown {
  throw 0;
}
let client3 = createClient([Module.Chat, Module.Video]);
// let client3: CommonModule & {
//     foo: VideoModule | ChatModule;
// }
```

you may see a union there. You must change it to intersection to work

```
// Either add this package as a dependency or copy-paste the needed types. No credit required.
// https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/union-to-intersection.d.ts
import { UnionToIntersection } from 'type-fest'

export type Core<T extends Module> = CommonModule & UnionToIntersection<ModulesMaps[T]>
export function createClient<T extends Module>(modules: T[]): Core<T> & unknown {
  // `& unknown` unwraps `Core<Module>` into `CommonModule & VideoModule & ChatModule`
  // this is for understandability, feel free to remove it for production
  throw 0;
}
let client3 = createClient([Module.Chat, Module.Video]);
// let client3: CommonModule & VideoModule & ChatModule
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. I don't have enough REPUTATION to cast a vote

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for @Dimava
I have found two ways to solve the problem.

### 1. Using `UnionToIntersection` in `type-fest` by @Dimava

```
export type UnionToIntersection<Union> = (
    // `extends unknown` is always going to be the case and is used to convert the
    // `Union` into a [distributive conditional
    // type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).
    Union extends unknown
        // The union type is used as the only argument to a function since the union
        // of function arguments is an intersection.
        ? (distributedUnion: Union) => void
        // This won't happen.
        : never
        // Infer the `Intersection` type since TypeScript represents the positional
        // arguments of unions of functions as an intersection of the union.
) extends ((mergedIntersection: infer Intersection) => void)
    ? Intersection
    : never;

export enum Module {
  'Video' = 0,
  'Chat',
}

export interface ModulesMaps {
  [Module.Video]: VideoModule;
  [Module.Chat]: ChatModule;
}

export interface VideoModule {
  getVideoModule():  string;
}

export interface ChatModule {
  getChatModule():  string;
}

export interface CommonModule {
  init(): void;
}

export type Core<T extends Module> = CommonModule & UnionToIntersection<ModulesMaps[T]>

export function createClient<T extends Module>(modules: T[]): Core<T> & unknown{
  throw 0;
}

let client1 = createClient([Module.Video]);
client1.getVideoModule();
client1.init();

let client2 = createClient([Module.Chat]);
client2.getChatModule();
client2.init();

let client3 = createClient([ Module.Chat, Module.Video  ]);
client3.getVideoModule(); //compile error
client3.getChatModule(); //compile error
client3.init();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AlhDAVCASQxmCgGdgBjGHDAHkzoD44BeOACgCgBIAen5wABqFIYAJuTgBXDAGsMEAO4ZhcLNICGAG2VbE0gOYQsGIwghwARqhgALVFS2U4WyRukzKEy3Cq4AG5k8A7AfIIiTLjqZjBWWnAA2hKaMFBY1jK0wf64qbS4uhFCSCgAupz2MDBg5ABcgsrNAHRlwORUGWAwOu5GLdBG-BIQVOT89u4S1hAQ8vxQwDrALsAAtEqkE%202d3TDrAEzrABwt1QC2OgDEqeTpmdlYwesBkliFGLrruwCULXxohg4GJgJIvAolKo%20AIhHhHLJsLgEMhUJpZD43NIwnBcDpEG4oEYZBcwaEEnAAGZyGh0ODkMxUOwIuR0GGRCCUqk0z6E4mkkjSdHuDQkMiUWm4AG8XgAfi4dweWVIEiB9XQSIwv3YrECpgk7Lh9nRylwAHJ4FMwCgMNLeOqMMBglBDXBiJSyAgEcJiKQKNRPup2vTGag8KiAMpdLA9OBLMBLSiCr2oSAMz7FGWRLREklk6ScxF0Atc6kYSUYbTaYFxcUBumFnGsqXcbWg8FcTikonACS%20usV9VmD1QN1i-0V7VsXX6358eX9iefPgOp1kADc3G4oEgsBBGBJcAAshAJDIVnAAN7cOBwM0ANSwEmAEDN7DgAAYADQ3u8AYSmGAzR-ABfLcd2geBaygSktCZY9T3PDojy0Oor1-JITzPFYWkfZ8IHKdU8JfLCkM3W9MMQnCAK0GBCLgGiYFIlZNzA7dwEg0U-Vg%20DiIgZjUGvW8jGAGA%20IEzhfnVekHnMVjwI4vdoJ41BGIE9DhNEtSqOASTpPuDI5O4NiIKU8cVIYiALguXB1KE0UPj0uA9SfeT2N3UJUUspZ6DwEEQHEKQEOw4BWA4P8rJsjB1IAMg1OgCEXCVPnoATyBQuokjwcpmAUjzuXLXkulWUg-x0LAyV8-zAukATmC7HSGjgPAknKKTvOAXzWDiuRFBUDB7IcKAVE-NyVngKhyrJABGd9ito4AyoqkhOEokLcKfF82s3SblpgaaWhEsTNv4nTJJ2qaSAOsxHN%20TduHG-xLpgQ45qWBalrJVaBJaRjtu4XayUOQ6tMAiS7oB57gZumBzq3R7AZIABmN6SsW57VuCpDfsAr8sZwvjb3%20xGYCRkHjvw8H1zgQQAguMAsAvMhhpdEmyaO7SQvOmn%20DphmmagFnIb2smYfOoA)

### 2. Use tuple types

```
// export type ModuleSelect<T extends Array<Module>, TModuleSelect extends Record<Module, any>> = (0 extends keyof T
//   ? TModuleSelect[T[0]]
//   : Record<string, never>) &
//   (1 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[1]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (2 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[2]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (3 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[3]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (4 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[4]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (5 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[5]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (6 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[6]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (7 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[7]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (8 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[8]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (9 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[9]] : Record<string, never>) &
//   (10 extends keyof T ? TModuleSelect[T[10]] : Record<string, never>);

export type ModuleSelect<T extends readonly Module[], TModuleSelect extends Record<Module, any>> =   | 
T extends [infer F extends Module, ...infer L extends readonly Module[]] ? TModuleSelect[F] & ModuleSelect<L, TModuleSelect>   : unknown;

export enum Module {
  'Video' = 0,
  'Chat',
}

export interface ModulesMaps {
  [Module.Video]: VideoModule;
  [Module.Chat]: ChatModule;
}

export interface VideoModule {
  getVideoModule(): string;
}

export interface ChatModule {
  getChatModule(): string;
}

export interface CommonModule {
  init(): void;
}

export type Core<T extends Array<Module>> = CommonModule & ModuleSelect<T, ModulesMaps>;

export function createClient<T extends Module[]>(_modules: [...T]): Core<T> {
  throw 0;
}

const client1 = createClient([Module.Video]);
client1.getVideoModule();
client1.init();

const client2 = createClient([Module.Chat]);
client2.getChatModule();
client2.init();

const client3 = createClient([Module.Chat, Module.Video]);
client3.getVideoModule();
client3.getChatModule();
client3.init();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyEAmBXANsAZWHwGMYAeAFTlBmADtMBnOAQSigENFyMd8AfABo4lPnkLFgZGiDqMWAJWnRMvLBJGd6iAQLgBeOAAoADLPnM4Aa2CIIAM1EAoOHAD8o8fiKkYAbUp-UwBdENc4AC44ZRJVciYYKABLegBzEXpgADdgKAEASjgAMgjjAEYLBitbeydqTzENHykyQP9ysKiYlSg1RJT0zJy8wpKygCYqhRs7R1EPL2bJP3aJrujY%20IHUjLgs3Pyi0rdjAGZpmrn6xab%20FekAoLONnri%20hKTd4cOxk5MACyXFi1eYNJb3XyPdoA15bD47Ib7EZHcanACswNmdQWjW8DzaQXRcN6-S%20SIOo2OZQAbFjQTc8csoYT-DSSe8yYM9pTUf9jAB2enXXEQiQsp7%20AUc7bknkov5lAAcwpx4Lu4takqVMoRcp%20VLRJgAnKqwbd8RL2sbdVzvsjftTTuVzLRqiCRerLVr2i7bZ9uQajgBuZzOUCQWA0ejYAC26GWcAA3hEAOQANWSmGAEFThjgpiEaYAwgALTgwVNFgC%20YYj0HgqToUAcnBIqHxTDQnDALBTbn8%20IAdJnsxAQtFRzn8aGB8OyxWJ3AFzAZ85a%20HwA24E28q323ApxB8cmImlgDAj-jjAVooi0qGN-Wo7uW23UCuT-24OeYJ-ljed5yo%20dZbi%209DNvuH4QLGsYQPQX4RKkyQwIBcDZBAWYgZukbwEgKDLtAwBUFi7BcDw%20J6PmxYwXBCGJsUCaQlqVAiJ23a9gIoY4duDjYPQZDJPBcAkFAwAVsAxa4MkDAUNQbozPi-ghAIxgAPpwfcTDRP4Q56ZQIS3oRYlUPo34wKWUAQAA7gW2FxPQiQidJsmVEYoniXQUkyRBxiDssI5ZjmhmhiQLkQeUQ6-leAEFKF4UwJFyGoXFYYOU5YU%20TAUzuWJEnebJfnzuWMAhc4mWyRMUUXv%209w3vFWVVcl9VpfBGUJRcuWeZJCVFQFK5sQFR5lRVEFnNVl5BcesUNbJ42-rVEgtaNMDjc1cVAA)

Comment: `export type ModuleSelect<T extends readonly Module[], TModuleSelect extends Record<Module, any>> =
  | T extends [infer F extends Module, ...infer L extends readonly Module[]] ? TModuleSelect[F] & ModuleSelect<L, TModuleSelect>
  : unknown;`